# "Open in" feature in Safari iOS 9 not working

Tags: safari, document, ios9, uti, document-types

my app uses a feature built into Safari's "Open in" when opening documents. I registered Document type like:

```
<dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
            <string>Microsoft Word</string>
            <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
            <array>
                <string>org.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document</string>
                <string>com.microsoft.word.openxmlformats.wordprocessingml.document</string>
            </array>
            <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
            <string>Alternate</string>
</dict>
```

In iOS 8, everything works fine and I can upload the document in my app. But with the release of iOS 9 this function is not working, Safari allows to open in my application only pdf files. Who knows why it stopped working in iOS 9.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Has this feature changed in iOS 9?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there was someone in the apple team thinking that this is too useful to be on an apple device and this should only be working to people using Android. And so they removed it. We can only hope that it will come back in a future update.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 9.1 this feature is working again.